# Who created the Uchiha's Clan's stone tablet in the Naka Shrine?

Tags: naruto

Deciphering the Uchiha's stone tablet, located in the Naka Shrine, requires the Mangekyou Sharingan or Rinnegan. However does the creation of the tablet require a Mangekyou and Rinnegan?

Rikudou Sennin had the Rinnegan and one of his sons who inherited his eye-techniques as the Mangekyou Sharingan.

What type of person was capable of creating this tablet?

Comment: I don't think the manga mentioned anything about who created the stone tablet or what type of person is he/she. Answers to this question would be merely speculations. Let's just wait until Kishimoto Masashi-sama mention about it.

Comment: @Sp0T: Wrong thread? :)

Comment: It's revealed in today's manga( ch 671) that Rikkudou Sennin created the stone tablet.

Comment: this question needs a change in accepted answer, or the currently accepted answer needs an update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, in manga version of naruto ([Chapter 671 Page 6](http://www.mangareader.net/naruto/671/6)), The Sage of Six Path mention that he left the stone monument so that people could reconsider. This is a concrete evidence that the Sage really created that stone monument. See image below (**Spoiler alert**):

> [image]

Answer (score 5):

Kishi never explicitly stated in the manga that Rikudou Sennin created the tablet, however we can make an educated guess that he did.

Let's take a look at the facts.

1. To read the entire Uchiha tablet, the Rinnegan is required.
2. Madara is stated to be the second Sage of the Six Paths. (This should mean no one else had the Rinnegan inbetween Rikudou Sennin and Madara.)
3. The tablet had an extensive list of things, like the Moon Eye plan, how to obtain Mangekyou Sharingan, how to obtain the Rinnegan, and the history of the God Tree with Kaguya.

Kaguya could not have written the tablet because most of the tablet's info pertain to Rikudou Sennin's era, where he had the Rinnegan and was the Juubi Jinchuriki. And since Kaguya isn't considered to be a Sage of Six paths, we can assume she doesn't have the Rinnegan either. We can also assume that a Rinnegan user must have written the tablet.

With that said, Rikudou and Madara are the only two candidates left, but Madara uses the tablet to learn about the history of Shinobi, so Rikudou is the only one who could have written the tablet.

EDIT: Additionally, Tobi stated the Sage of Six paths created the tablet here (bottom panels).

[image]